# Swipe between Views with constant overlay

Tags: android, xml, layout, overlay

I'm familiar with Android development, but I haven't coded in a while.  I'm unfamiliar with working with Fragments, so I just wanted to get some quick layout advice.

I'm creating an application where I want to swipe between different views, but also have a constant overlay at the bottom of the activity.  There will be three different views but I don't want tabs (TabHost, etc).  I just want to have a constant overlay that will display the name of the current view at the top, and a constant overlay at the bottom which will have the user's name and a button.  The three views will just be parsed JSON data.

I don't need to have a detailed description of how to do this, but any recommendations would be great!  I just have been out of the Android game for too long.

Here quick example picture of what I'm trying to create:
[image: Example]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: and use another font please

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need to have a detailed description of how to do this, but any
>   recommendations would be great! I just have been out of the Android
>   game for too long.

Place the two overlay views in a `RelativeLayout`, one aligned to the top of the `RelativeLayout` and one aligned to the bottom of the `RelativeLayout`. For swiping the json based views use a `ViewPager`. I don't know if you want the two overlay views to be **on top** of the `ViewPager`'s content or the entire `ViewPager` content **between** the two overlays, depending on what you want you'll either place the `ViewPager` between the two previous view in the `RelativeLayout` or simply set if to fill the `RelativeLayout`(and be placed below them).

Answer (score 1):

For your simplicity , adding few code that is available on the internet.

```
public class AwesomePagerActivity extends Activity {

private ViewPager awesomePager;
private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 20;
private Context cxt;
private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_awesome_pager);
    cxt = this;

    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
    awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
}

private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        TextView text = new TextView(cxt);
        text.setTextSize(50);
                    text.setText("Text"+position);
        collection.addView(text, 0);

        return text;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((TextView) view);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(ViewGroup arg0) {
    }
            @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
           }
         }
```

you can add images instead of creating new TextView's. Just add ViewPager in your xml where you want to change the views.No need to create Fragments just create new View(could be anything Image, TextView etc.) according to your need.

adding xml also for better understanding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/awesomepager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where does awesomepager get defined?  ( in reference to the line findViewById(R.id.awesomepager); )

Answer (score 0):

You need to create PagerAdapter like this:

```
public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

List<View> pages = null;

public SamplePagerAdapter(List<View> pages){
    this.pages = pages;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
    View v = pages.get(position);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view){
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return pages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(View arg0){
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1){
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState(){
    return null;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View arg0){
}
```

}

Then create fragmnet and place code like this to onCreateView

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();

    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText("page1");
    pages.add(page);

    page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
    textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText("page2");
    pages.add(page);

    page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
    textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText("page 3");
    pages.add(page);

    SamplePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(pages);
    ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);     

    setContentView(viewPager);
```

And create some interface to listen ViewChange on your fragment, and pass current page thru interface to main activity. That`s all folks :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but it might be useful for others looking for an answer.

Another option is to use a `FrameLayout` that hosts your ViewPager along with buttons/text/whatever else you want.

Here's an example to give you an idea:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- ViewPager for main screen -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

**NOTE**: The order is important! The view that is defined first will go underneath all the others.